# Using Game Center to save/share game data/state

Tags: ios, save, game-center

After reading the [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH1-SW1) and hours of searching various forums I can't seem to find information on how this is done.

Basically I have a bunch of data that I save locally that makes up the current state of the player's game.  I've seen other games such as Tiny Tower, Pocket Planes and Smurf's village actually backs that data up in Game Center.

My goal here is for players to be able to load up data from their friend's games so they can see how things are progressing.  For example, in Tiny Tower I can view my friend's tower and send him/her gifts.  Similarly in Smurf's Village.  I know I can do this with my own server with login/password but if it works via Game Center why complicate things?

Is it a matter of exploiting Game Center's match functionality?  Or leaderboards? Or?

Anyway can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: those games likely implement their own back end to support this functionality.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a missing piece from Game Center if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through this tutorial, and it sounds like it would answer a lot of questions that you have.

[What's New With Game Center In iOS6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20RayWenderlich%20%28Ray%20Wenderlich%20%7C%20iPhone%20Developer%20and%20Gamer%29)

Comment: Thanks AJak, I have seen this tutorial and it's more about getting GC setup and uploading scores.  What I'm looking for is something beyond the basics. Also this isn't new to ios6 I've seen this in many games for at least a year or two.